# Flutter. Как отобразить Future<List<Product>> в интерфейсе

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart, flutter-ui

Есть метод с запросом:

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://fakestoreapi.com/products'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    Iterable l = json.decode(response.body);
    List<Product> products= List<Product>.from(l.map((i) => Product.fromJson(i)));
    return products;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Он возвращает список продуктов из фейк магазина: https://fakestoreapi.com/

Как отобразить к примеру `title` второго элемента ?
Верстка:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Product>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.title);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Объект:

```
class Product {
  final int id;
  final String title, description, category;
  final double price;
  final String image;
  final Map rating;

  Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.category,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.image,
    @required this.rating
  });

  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      category: json['category'],
      price: json['price'],
      image: json['image'],
      rating: json['rating'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: А что собственно не работает?

Comment: @MiT Вопрос не в том что не работает, А в том как теперь этот список передать на интерфейс, после получения
Через future не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дженерик FutureBuilder указан неправильно. Он должен быть таким же, как возвращаем значение future. Тогда можно будет обратиться ко второму элементу
snapshot.data.products[2].title

Comment: И future: fetchAlbum

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).